# Capture unknown stream with gstreamer

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer, video-capture

I have an IP camera which streams H264 video over UDP, however I can't capture it with gstreamer in any usable quality.

With this command:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -vvv playbin uri=udp://192.168.1.66:30120
```

I get the picture from the camera but it has latency of several seconds. It does produce the flowing output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: ring-buffer-max-size = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-size = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-duration = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: use-buffering = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: download = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: uri = udp://192.168.1.66:30120
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: connection-speed = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstUDPSrc\)\ source"
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:src_0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)nal
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)nal
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstMultiQueuePad:sink_0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)nal
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4, codec_data=(buffer)014d4028ffe1002d674d4028e7281687b602200001f4000075301c00000763b000005f5e11ffff1800000ec7600000bebc23fffe0401000468fe3c80
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
Redistribute latency...
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/avdec_h264:avdec_h264-0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4, codec_data=(buffer)014d4028ffe1002d674d4028e7281687b602200001f4000075301c00000763b000005f5e11ffff1800000ec7600000bebc23fffe0401000468fe3c80
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4, codec_data=(buffer)014d4028ffe1002d674d4028e7281687b602200001f4000075301c00000763b000005f5e11ffff1800000ec7600000bebc23fffe0401000468fe3c80
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4, codec_data=(buffer)014d4028ffe1002d674d4028e7281687b602200001f4000075301c00000763b000005f5e11ffff1800000ec7600000bebc23fffe0401000468fe3c80
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/avdec_h264:avdec_h264-0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: always-ok = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: active = true
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0: active-pad = "\(GstSelectorPad\)\ sink_0"
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink.GstGhostPad:video_sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad4: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstStreamSynchronizer:streamsynchronizer0.GstPad:src_0: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vdbin.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad8: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vdbin/GstVideoConvert:vdconv.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vdbin/GstDeinterlace:deinterlace.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vdbin.GstGhostPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad7: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstQueue:vqueue.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstQueue:vqueue.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstQueue:vqueue.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vdbin/GstDeinterlace:deinterlace.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vdbin/GstVideoConvert:vdconv.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vdbin.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstStreamSynchronizer:streamsynchronizer0.GstPad:sink_0: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstStreamSynchronizer:streamsynchronizer0.GstPad:sink_0: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink.GstGhostPad:video_sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0.GstGhostPad:src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad3: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad2: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoConvert:conv.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoScale:scale.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoBalance:videobalance.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoConvert:conv2.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv.GstGhostPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstD3DVideoSink:d3dvideosink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv.GstGhostPad:src.GstProxyPad:proxypad6: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoConvert:conv2.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoBalance:videobalance.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoScale:scale.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoConvert:conv.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
Redistribute latency...
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)H.264;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)";
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2954640, maximum-bitrate=(uint)2954640, bitrate=(uint)3746160;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2940000, maximum-bitrate=(uint)2954640, bitrate=(uint)3672872;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2940000, maximum-bitrate=(uint)2979120, bitrate=(uint)3615060;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2940000, maximum-bitrate=(uint)2985360, bitrate=(uint)3566621;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2940000, maximum-bitrate=(uint)3008160, bitrate=(uint)3526731;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2884800, maximum-bitrate=(uint)3008160, bitrate=(uint)3483936;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2825280, maximum-bitrate=(uint)3061920, bitrate=(uint)3206312;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2825280, maximum-bitrate=(uint)3061920, bitrate=(uint)3271864;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2884800, maximum-bitrate=(uint)3061920, bitrate=(uint)3317603;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2884800, maximum-bitrate=(uint)3061920, bitrate=(uint)3384492;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2884800, maximum-bitrate=(uint)3045840, bitrate=(uint)3402413;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2884800, maximum-bitrate=(uint)3013920, bitrate=(uint)3423388;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2825280, maximum-bitrate=(uint)3061920, bitrate=(uint)3140596;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2825280, maximum-bitrate=(uint)10467840, bitrate=(uint)3296509;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2825280, maximum-bitrate=(uint)10467840, bitrate=(uint)3230234;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2825280, maximum-bitrate=(uint)10467840, bitrate=(uint)3165169;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2825280, maximum-bitrate=(uint)10535760, bitrate=(uint)3216146;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2354640, maximum-bitrate=(uint)10535760, bitrate=(uint)3201875;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2286000, maximum-bitrate=(uint)10535760, bitrate=(uint)3159590;
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0: tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(Main\ Profile\)", minimum-bitrate=(uint)2286000, maximum-bitrate=(uint)10535760, bitrate=(uint)3096548;
```

With that output I have tried to write an alternative pipeline that would produce better results. So far I have:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc port=30120 ! video/x-raw, packetsize=(int)188, format=(string)RGB16, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! autovideosink
```

but this only displays a black screen. And this:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -vvv udpsrc port=30120 ! video/x-raw, packetsize=(int)188, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! autovideosink
```

only shows a green screen.

What would be the optimal pipeline for my stream? Is it even possible to do this with Gstreamer?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Running gst-discoverer i got:

```
c:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\bin>gst-discoverer-1.0.exe udp://192.168.1.66:30120
Analyzing udp://192.168.1.66:30120
Done discovering udp://192.168.1.66:30120

Topology:
  container: MPEG-2 Transport Stream
    audio: MPEG-2 AAC
      audio: MPEG-4 AAC
    video: H.264 (High Profile)

Properties:
  Duration: 99:99:99.999999999
  Seekable: no
  Tags:
      audio codec: MPEG-2 AAC
      minimum bitrate: 125250
      maximum bitrate: 125250
      bitrate: 125362
      video codec: H.264
```

How do I turn this into a pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below pipeline for receiving H264 streams on UDP

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=30120 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, 
clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! 
rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

To know how to use gstreamer plugins checkout this site 
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html

Comment: I have tried your pipeline, and have spent too much time in the documentation, but I can't figure this out. I've edited my question with new information. Thank you.